# How to make D3.js use UTC times for the x-axis, with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, momentjs

I'm using D3.js to draw a zoomable chart with a UTC time scale for the x-axis, e.g.:

```
var axisTimeFormat = d3.time.format.utc.multi([
    [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
    [":%S", function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
    ["%I:%M", function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
    ["%I %p", function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
    ["%a %d", function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
    ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
    ["%B", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
    ["%Y", function() { return true; }]
]);

// `minDt` and `maxDt` are Moment.js UTC times:
var x = d3.time.scale.utc()
          .domain([minDt, maxDt])
          .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
              .orient('bottom')
              .tickSize(-height)
              .tickFormat(axisTimeFormat);
```

My data uses Moment.js UTC times. It all works, but the problem is that the ticks are always of the format "%I %p", no matter how much I've zoomed in or out.

I'm in London, during daylight savings, so in `d3.time.format.utc.multi`, `d.getHours()` is returning either `1` or `13`, rather than `0` (which would cause it to fall through to the next time format) or `12`.

It seems that the Date objects being used in those functions are no longer UTC. i.e. if I do `console.log(d)` in one of them I get something like:

```
Tue May 16 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

How can I make these use the UTC dates that I'm using everywhere else?

Comment: I don't see moment in your code at all.  If you actually got `d` by `yourUtcMomentObject.toDate()`, then just don't call `toDate`.  You can take the values from moment's getters, like `.hour()`, etc.

Comment: `minDt` and `maxDt`, used to generate the D3 scale, are both Moment times. But `d`, within the functions in `d3.time.format.utc.multi()` are all standard JS dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UTC methods in your axisTimeFormat definition.

Try replacing

```
return d.getHours();
```

with

```
return d.getUTCHours();
```

and so on

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I noticed those methods earlier today in my timezone adventures and then forgot all about them.